# Send user location to WhatsApp android studio

Tags: java, android, location, whatsapp

Looking for some direction is it possible to send a location message to a whatsapp contact from an android app in java code. I need my users to be able to share their locations with people outside the app for delivery purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Simpley register location listener and inside onLocationChanged method grab you current user latitude and longitude and build Google maps url from this.

Here is sample code

```
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    String coordinates = latitude + "," + longitude;

    // Share the location using an intent to open it in Google Maps
    String mapsUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=" + coordinates;
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(mapsUrl));
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: The question is more about sharing someone else's location to some one else